# A bit lost with ILMerge

Tags: c#, dll, ilmerge

Thanks for taking some time to help me out.
Using: Microsoft Visual C# 2010 Express

I have two files: RJFCModPackInstaller.exe and Ionic.Zip.dll That i'd like to merge in to one: RJFCModpackInstaller.exe

I've tried to do post-build and havetried multiple GUIs, what can/should I do?

I tried using this:

```
"$(SolutionDir)ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /out:"$(SolutionDir)\deploy\$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)*.dll" /target:exe /targetplatform:'v4, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319' /wildcards
```

But came out with this error:

```
Error   2   The command ""C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" /out:"C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\\deploy\RJFCModPackInstaller.exe" "C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\RJFCModPackInstaller\bin\Release\RJFCModPackInstaller.exe" "C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\RJFCModPackInstaller\bin\Release\*.dll" /target:exe /targetplatform:'v4, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319' /wildcards" exited with code 3.   RJFCModPackInstaller
```

**EDIT:**
If I change the code to:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe /out:"$(SolutionDir)deploy\$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)*.dll" /target:exe /targetplatform:'v4, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319' /wildcards
```

I get error 9009:

```
Error   1   The command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\ILMerge\ILMerge.exe /out:"C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\deploy\RJFCModPackInstaller.exe" "C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\RJFCModPackInstaller\bin\Debug\RJFCModPackInstaller.exe" "C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\RJFCModPackInstaller\bin\Debug\*.dll" /target:exe /targetplatform:'v4, C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319' /wildcards" exited with code 9009.  RJFCModPackInstaller
```

Comment: Windows error code 3 is "The system cannot find the path specified." or ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND. This indicates a problem with a path and not a file name.

Comment: Ya 2010 sorry. I'm ridiculously tired haha. Have to figure this out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's an extra `\` here:

```
/out:"C:\Users\FusionD\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\RJFCModPackInstaller\\deploy
                                                                                          ^
                                                                                          |
```

So I'd suggest changing

```
$(SolutionDir)\deploy
```

to

```
$(SolutionDir)deploy
```

---

The 9009 error is because you've removed the quotes from around the command now (so it's trying to execute `C:\Program`). Put those quotes back (or revert to your original command, just without the extra `\`).