# The command exited with a code of 3 error (ILmerge)

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, dll, ilmerge

I'm using VS 2012, before I got the error below, I was getting a 9009 error which I resolved by putting my post build in quotations. Now I got this  belowerror and I'm not understanding what it means or how to resolve it.

Any ideas?

Error   1   The command ""ilmerge /out:secfg.exe secfg_out.exe CommandLine.dll"" exited with code 3.    secfg
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9835494/a-bit-lost-with-ilmerge. It looks like a bad path

Comment: A bad path where? I checked my output window and t's displaying the correct path.
1>  secfg -> C:\tfs\MyStuff\SecureConfig\secfg\bin\Debug\secfg_out.exe
1>  The system cannot find the path specified.

Comment: I don't have a clue where your bad path may be.  Try using SysInternals' Process Monitor to figure it out.  Is `ilmerge` running with the current directly set to where you expect things to be?  There are macros (that work both within VS and within MSBuild) that return just about every folder you might be interested in